# Nuxt/Vue Hydration issue when using a slotted component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a new nuxt project where I am experiencing some strange hydration issues. I've tried to isolate the issue as much as possible to demonstrate (see image).

The hydration error only occurs intermittently.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Group.vue - A component with a slot and renders a label prop

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ label }}
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  defineProps(['label'])
</script>
```

new-form-2.vue - renders the Group component with an input in the slot

```
<template>
  <Group label="firstname">
    <input type="text">
  </Group>
</template>
```

default.vue - an empty layout component with a slot in

```
<template>
    <slot />
</template>
```

```
chunk-BVQHDTV7.js:1449 [Vue warn]: Hydration children mismatch in <div>: server rendered element contains more child nodes than client vdom. 
  at <Group label="firstname" > 
  at <NewForm2 onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouteProvider key="/new-form-2" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/new-form-2', hash: '', query: {…}, name: 'new-form-2', path: '/new-form-2', …}  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <Default ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} name="default" > 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGS8q.png)

I've tried to isolate the issue as much as possible, but it's still not clear why the hydration issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch in child nodes occurs when there's a difference in the number or structure of elements between server and client rendering.

Wrap your new-form2.vue with

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Group label="firstname">
      <input type="text">
    </Group>
  </div>
</template>
```

By wrapping content in a  as above, you ensure that the structure is consistent between the server-rendered HTML and the client-side vDOM, which should resolve the hydration error.

also you need to wrap your layout/default.vue as well..

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  <div>
</template>
```

learn more here
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts

Comment: Hi Imgrv, thanks for your response. I tried the updated code and the hydration issue no longer appears. I did try to get the error to appear with my original code but the hydration error isn't coming back. Maybe it was originally caused by caching or something environmental.